# Interactive Grid - filter on column with multiple values (Oracle APEX 19.2)

Tags: oracle-apex

I found out when I'm creating a Interactive Grid and making one column a checkbox with LOV from shared components and i switch atributte (Column Filter) "Enabled" for true, there is no option to put fillter on this column from action menu.

Is there a option to make a filter on a column with multivalues?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to enable filters for multi value columns. Technically it's not easy to implement, but we are looking into it and are tracking it with bug# 25565254.

Regards APEX team